# apache drill invalid username and password error

Tags: linux, apache-drill, pam, amazon-linux

I have setup Apache Drill version 1.21.1 in distributed mode on 3 nodes with ZK & 3 nodes with drill.

Now, I am trying to configure Plain Authentication in Drill using PAM. I already have 1 existing users in the 3 nodes with same password and they are present in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow.

I have followed the steps mentioned here, to configure authentication setup on the Drill cluster.

But, on entering correct username and password, it throws Invalid Username/Password error.

this is my drill configuration

```
drill.exec: {
                      cluster-id: "drillbits1",
                      zk.connect="zkip1:2181,zkip1:2181,zkip1:2181",
                      impersonation: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    max_chained_user_hops: 3
                                  },
                                  security: {
                                          auth.mechanisms : ["PLAIN"],
                                            },
                                    security.user.auth: {
                                            enabled: true,
                                            packages += "org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security",
                                            impl: "pam4j",
                                            pam_profiles: [ "sudo", "login" ]
```

I have configured 3 nodes with load balancer so that all the nodes accessible by single url..

Im Querying the data from superset ...

but some times it throws invalid username and password error (auth_error)

when I restart the drill node it works fine for some times....again it throws auth error...

here is the error showing in drill log

```
- PAM auth failed for user: supersetuser against sudo profile. Exception: pam_authenticate failed : Authentication failure
```

is this issue debug level is linux level or do we need to alter anything in config file of drill...??

Comment: Can you see any clue in any of the the /var/log/auth.log files?